# How to skip Unicode Errors in a url

Tags: python, urllib, python-unicode

I am trying to figure out how to handle Unicode Errors in Python and skip them.
I guess I have to use the structure try, except UnicodeError but I don't know what to place in the UnicodeError condition to skip that URL and continue scraping. Here is my code:

```
  File "imagescraper.py", line 24, in <module>
    urllib.urlretrieve(image, "image0"+str(page)+str(i)+".jpg")
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 94, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 228, in retrieve
    url = unwrap(toBytes(url))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1055, in toBytes
    " contains non-ASCII characters")
UnicodeError: URL u'http://blogging.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/design-p\xe1gina-de-fans.png' contains non-ASCII characters
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try using a "pass" statement inside of your "except" block? Sorry if that's oversimplifying things, just not sure what you tried, or what your code looks like (maybe you could paste that in too?).

Comment: Extending @Nacho's reasoning, I'm going to go out on a limb and see you want either `pass` or `continue`.

Comment: That what you post not seems to be your code, is more like the error you get when hit some unicode charatcer. Could you post your actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this seems to be what you desire:

```
except UnicodeError:
    pass
```

[`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/simple_stmts.html#pass) is basically just a placeholder, it does nothing. The exception is handled by the `except` block, and then `pass` will allow you to move on to your next URL.

Note that if you are doing it within a loop, use the [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement) keyword instead- this moves on to the next cycle of the loop within which it is immediately.

Comment: Alex, for that second bit about continue, it depends on whether or not he wants any code within the loop after the try/except to execute, right? Maybe just a little clarification on that second sentence? Might not be the common case, but hard to tell without seeing his code.

Comment: @Nacho It should work fine as long as OP has put the applicable code in a `finally` block. It would be executed before the `continue` flow. Otherwise, the idea of the code seems fairly simple. I doubt there would be too many complexities outside of checking for OK URLs within that loop.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of skipping the URL, just encode it to a valid URL:

```
import urllib, urlparse

parts = urlparse.urlsplit(image)
parts = parts._replace(path=urllib.quote(parts.path.encode('utf8')))
image = parts.geturl()
```

This turns:

```
http://blogging.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/design-página-de-fans.png
```

into

```
http://blogging.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/design-p%C3%A1gina-de-fans.png
```